# replacing texexec with context when compiling from auctex

Tags: context, auctex

When I launch the ConTeXt command from AucTEX Command menu (or with C-c C-c), AucTEX calls for texexec and compilation fails since texexec relies on ruby dependencies that are not installed under my Windows account. This piece of code may be somehow outdated: AFAIK, texexec is rather designed for MkII. Moreover, it would be good to be free to choose context or contextjit.

Of course under Emacs everything can be configured. I looked for a way to change the texexec variable to context in my .emacs. All I could find is that TeX-command-default, when set to 'ConTeXt', launches texexec. I do not know how to change this.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To switch to MKIV in Emacs, set [ConTeXt-Mark-version](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-ConTeXt_002dMark_002dversion)

```lisp
(setq ConTeXt-Mark-version "IV")
```

in your `.emacs`.  By default the `ConTeXt` command in Emacs executes `context --once`.  I don't like this and want to take advantage of the automatic multipass compilation of ConTeXt, so I switch to `ConTeXt Full` by default.

```lisp
(add-hook 'ConTeXt-mode-hook
          (lambda()
            (setq TeX-command-default "ConTeXt Full")))
```

If you are like me and do not save ConTeXt files with a `.tex` extension but rather `.mkiv` or even `.mkvi`, then you also need the following part, such that ConTeXt is enabled when you open these files and that AUCTeX knows the extension when compiling:

```lisp
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mkiv\\'" . ConTeXt-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.mkvi\\'" . ConTeXt-mode))
(with-eval-after-load "context"
  (add-to-list 'TeX-file-extensions "mkvi" t)
  (add-to-list 'TeX-file-extensions "mkiv" t))
```

Comment: Thanks. I once searched AucTeX wiki for all occurences of ConTeXt but didn't figured out that a switch to MkIV would solve it, because I read it when I was still thinking that texexec worked on both mkii and mkiv.

Comment: may i paste your solution to emacswiki's AUCTeX page?

Comment: @sztruks Sure, but I am no Emacs expert.  Surely, there is a way to do this more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Henri's answer is thorough.

On any AUCTeX precompiled package from a GNU/Linux distribution out there you can have:

```lisp
 (load "context.el" nil t t)
```

on your init file instead, as long as you modify **II** with **IV** on `context.el`. Save and exit.

```lisp
 ;; Define before first use.
 (defcustom ConTeXt-Mark-version "IV"
   "ConTeXt Mark version used for running ConTeXt."
   :type 'string
   :group 'TeX-command)
 (make-variable-buffer-local 'ConTeXt-Mark-version)
 (put 'ConTeXt-Mark-version 'safe-local-variable 'stringp)
```

The file **context.el** may be found at `/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/auctex` directory

There are other questions that deal with a standalone ConTeXt such as https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33879. For those cases which deal with PATH start all over.

Comment: You suggest that one should **modify** `context.el`?

Comment: @ArashEsbati hehehe, the source says to define `defcustom`. Defcustom was suggested by my dear fellow Tassilo at one point, and I think the no less than great Mose expanded upon it. I've personally changed it in the past until I came across https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2016-09/msg00002.html but for some reason I' d always forget what the variable name was. Then I wanted to "run" only "pre-compiled" packages. Auctex 12.1-1 was on the community repository and it was viable to do so without having to remember such variable. But I'm wondering, isn't your end goal to merge with Emacs?

Comment: The source says to define `ConTeXt-Mark-version` before first use of the variable in order to silence the compiler.  See [this patch](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/auctex.git/commit/context.el?id=8459946331371c36de17341f2320fe831dad2e21) where the code was relocated within `context.el`.   I don't know what you mean by "pre-complied" packages, but please do not advertise to modify original lisp files.  Reg. Emacs integration: I wouldn't hold my breath for that.  My personal opinion is that ELPA releases are a good choice for AUCTeX.

Comment: @ArashEsbati "Do not advertise to modify original lisp files"... I have no idea what you implied or imagined... I can't advertise, for there is nothing to advertise, but as long as I'm not being imposed to compile ffrom source (which you clearly didn't suggested to), or use ELPA for every other need, I have to, out of necessity, make modifications to any lisp file that's on the way. Ahem.. can I for example, change some parts of the `context-en.el` that have been poorly implemented? Or should I post my concern on the mailing list?